# В чём ошибка? Неправильно работает, если в ответе нужно вывести несколько параллелей

Tags: python

Задача в следующем: на вход даётся имя, фамилия и класс ученика(1-12, а-я). Нужно подсчитать количество учеников в каждой параллели, сравнить, вывести максимальное значение и, собственно эти параллели( 92 / 3 5 11). Если выводится одна параллель, то значение верное, а если уже две, то ответ неверный...
Сам код:

```
def isint(value): 
    try:
        int(value)
    return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

N = int(input()) 
k = 12
KolvoVParallelyah = [0]*k 


for i in range(0, N):
    Dannie_0 = input() 
    Dannie_1 = Dannie_0.split()
    Dannie_2 = str(Dannie_1[-1])
    Nomer = []

    for c in Dannie_2:
        if isint(c):
            Nomer.append(c)
        else:
            break
    Nomer_1 = "".join(Nomer)
    Nomer_klassa = int(Nomer_1)
    KolvoVParallelyah[Nomer_klassa] += 1

Parallely = []
Maximum = max(KolvoVParallelyah)
Index = KolvoVParallelyah.index(Maximum)

for d in range(0, len(KolvoVParallelyah)):
    Chislo = max(KolvoVParallelyah)
    if Chislo == Maximum:
        Klass = KolvoVParallelyah.index(Chislo) 
        Parallely.append(Klass)
        del KolvoVParallelyah[Index]
        KolvoVParallelyah.insert(0,0)
    else:
        break

print(Maximum)
print(Parallely)
```

Comment: данные то дайте.

Comment: @AndrioSkur Да рандомные вбивала...

Comment: @AndrioSkur Это школьная задачка.